# Problem multiple scripts become running through the same script AHK?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

Sometimes when I reload a script, the same script becomes running through the same script multiple time in the task bar as shown in this picture :

[image]

Known that I had only one script was running.

This happens to me sometimes in AHK V1 and V2.

Does anyone know what's the problem?

This is what I have in the Auto execute section

Is there something causing the problem?

```
#SingleInstance Force
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
Persistent
SetWorkingDir(A_ScriptDir) ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetTitleMatchMode 2
A_MaxHotkeysPerInterval := 99000000
A_HotkeyInterval := 99000000
ProcessSetPriority("A")
FileEncoding("UTF-8-RAW")
SetKeyDelay(-1, -1)
SetMouseDelay(-1)
SetDefaultMouseSpeed(0)
SetWinDelay(-1)
SetControlDelay(-1)
SendMode("Input")
DllCall("Sleep", "UInt", 1) ;I just slept exactly 1ms!ujkjhglkj
DetectHiddenText(true)
TraySetIcon("C:\Users\th\VSCC\Icon kha\2resum.png", "1")
#include %A_ScriptDir%\keys 2.ahk
#include %A_ScriptDir%\fucs 2.ahk
#include %A_ScriptDir%\Anki 2.ahk
#include %A_ScriptDir%\vivaldi 2.ahk
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\ToolTipOptions 2.ahk
; =================================================================
SetTimer freload, 1000
SetTimer music, 100
SetTimer error_2kha, 2000
SetTimer FormReminder, 1000
SetTimer Form_Whats, 1000
SetTimer esalat, 1000
SetTimer IObitPdf, 1000
SetTimer DarkTitleBar, 1000
SetTimer Vidmore_Fatal, 2000
; =================================================================
ToolTipOptions.Init()
ToolTipOptions.SetFont("s20 italic", "Consolas")
ToolTipOptions.SetColors("Black", "red")
; =================================================================
Global GLang := ""
Global name_to_mod := false
Global mod_txt_as := false
Global mod_bin_as := false
Global wait_RCtrl_RButton := false
global k_var := false
global stt := false
```

Comment: See [Debugging a Script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Scripts.htm#debug). You can also add MsgBox, ToolTips, FileAppend and the like in an [OnExit Function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/OnExit.htm#function) and in the auto-execute section to see how the script behaves before exiting and after restarting.